# How to find fill values that represent the reason for no data in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want evapotranspiration data and use the "MOD16A2.006: Terra Net Evapotranspiration 8-Day Global 500m" dataset on Google Earth Engine. In Google Earth Engine, pixels with no calculated ET values have "masked" value. However, according to MOD16A2.006 Userguide, "MOD16A2.006" has 7 types of fill values which represent the reason for no value. (e.g."land cover assigned as urban/built-up")
I want to get fill values data that represent the reason for no ET value.
How can I get GeoTIFFs with fill values data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the "Layers" section of [the dataset docs](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mod16a2v006), the class assignment in fill values 32761 through 32767 might be inaccurate. They are not included in the Earth Engine assets.

> Users are asked to disregard the class assignments for Fill Values 32761 through 32767 irrespective of the assigned quality for these pixels. Class assignments may be incorrect and users are advised to exercise caution while using the product in their application. See known issue [PM_MOD16_18074](https://landweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/QA_WWW/displayCase.cgi?esdt=MOD16&caseNum=PM_MOD16_18074&caseLocation=cases_data&type=C6&_ga=2.43830823.344616390.1604679344-1779901005.1604679344) for further information.